# shader can't read data except position, texcoord, normal

Tags: animation, directx, hlsl, graphics-programming, skinning

i want to read bone's weight but shader can't read data

this is my vertex type

```
struct SkinnedMesh
{

XMFLOAT3 Position;
XMFLOAT2 Texture;
XMFLOAT3 Normal;
XMFLOAT3 Weight;
UINT BoneIndices[4];
};
```

this is initialize shader code

```
ID3D10Blob* vertexShaderBuffer;
ID3D10Blob* pixelShaderBuffer;
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC polygonLayout[5];
unsigned int numElements;
DWORD ShaderFlag = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS | D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;

// Initialize the pointers this function will use to null.
vertexShaderBuffer = nullptr;
pixelShaderBuffer = nullptr;

// Initialize the pointers this function will use to null.
vertexShaderBuffer = nullptr;
pixelShaderBuffer = nullptr;

// Compile the vertex shader code.
if (FAILED(D3DCompileFromFile(_VSPath.c_str(), NULL, NULL, "main", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlag, 0, &vertexShaderBuffer, NULL)))
{
    MSG_BOX("Failed to compile vertex shader.");
    return E_FAIL;
}

// Compile the pixel shader code.
if (FAILED(D3DCompileFromFile(_PSPath.c_str(), NULL, NULL, "main", "ps_4_0", D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, &pixelShaderBuffer, NULL)))
{
    MSG_BOX("Failed to compile pixel shader.");
    return E_FAIL;
}

// Create the vertex shader from the buffer.
if (FAILED(_Device->CreateVertexShader(vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, VertexShader.GetAddressOf())))
{
    MSG_BOX("Failed to create vertex shader from buffer.");
    return E_FAIL;
}

// Create the pixel shader from the buffer.
if (FAILED(_Device->CreatePixelShader(pixelShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), pixelShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, PixelShader.GetAddressOf())))
{
    MSG_BOX("Failed to create pixel shader from buffer.");
    return E_FAIL;
}

// Create the vertex input layout description.
polygonLayout[0].SemanticName = "POSITION";
polygonLayout[0].SemanticIndex = 0;
polygonLayout[0].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
polygonLayout[0].InputSlot = 0;
polygonLayout[0].AlignedByteOffset = 0;
polygonLayout[0].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
polygonLayout[0].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

polygonLayout[1].SemanticName = "TEXCOORD";
polygonLayout[1].SemanticIndex = 0;
polygonLayout[1].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
polygonLayout[1].InputSlot = 0;
polygonLayout[1].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
polygonLayout[1].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
polygonLayout[1].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

polygonLayout[2].SemanticName = "NORMAL";
polygonLayout[2].SemanticIndex = 0;
polygonLayout[2].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
polygonLayout[2].InputSlot = 0;
polygonLayout[2].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
polygonLayout[2].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
polygonLayout[2].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

polygonLayout[3].SemanticName = "BLENDWEIGHT";
polygonLayout[3].SemanticIndex = 0;
polygonLayout[3].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
polygonLayout[3].InputSlot = 0;
polygonLayout[3].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
polygonLayout[3].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
polygonLayout[3].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

polygonLayout[4].SemanticName = "BLENDINDICES";
polygonLayout[4].SemanticIndex = 0;
polygonLayout[4].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT;
polygonLayout[4].InputSlot = 0;
polygonLayout[4].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
polygonLayout[4].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
polygonLayout[4].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

numElements = sizeof(polygonLayout) / sizeof(polygonLayout[0]);

// Create the vertex input layout.8
if (FAILED(_Device->CreateInputLayout(polygonLayout, numElements, vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(), &Layout)))
{
    MSG_BOX("Failed to create vertex input layout.");
    return E_FAIL;
}

// Release the vertex shader buffer and pixel shader buffer since they are no longer needed.
vertexShaderBuffer->Release();
vertexShaderBuffer = nullptr;

pixelShaderBuffer->Release();
pixelShaderBuffer = nullptr;

// 텍스처 샘플러 생태 구조체 생성 및 설정
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDecs;
samplerDecs.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR; // 텍스쳐를 어떻게 처리 할 것인지
samplerDecs.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;  // UV좌표 0~1 사이에 모든 이미지가 오게 설정
samplerDecs.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;  // UV좌표 0~1 사이에 모든 이미지가 오게 설정
samplerDecs.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;  // UV좌표 0~1 사이에 모든 이미지가 오게 설정
samplerDecs.MipLODBias = 0.f;                         // 아래부터 그냥 Default
samplerDecs.MaxAnisotropy = 1;
samplerDecs.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
samplerDecs.BorderColor[0] = 0;
samplerDecs.BorderColor[1] = 0;
samplerDecs.BorderColor[2] = 0;
samplerDecs.BorderColor[3] = 0;
samplerDecs.MinLOD = 0;
samplerDecs.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

if (FAILED(_Device->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDecs, 
 &SampleState)))
{
    MSG_BOX("Failed to create SamplerState.");
    return E_FAIL;
}
return S_OK;
```

this is hlsl code

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix WorldMatrix;
    matrix ViewMatrix;
    matrix ProjectionMatrix;

}
struct SkinnedInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
    float3 Weights : BLENDWEIGHT;
    uint4 BoneIndices : BLENDINDICES;
};

struct SkinnedOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
};

SkinnedOutput main(SkinnedInput _Input)
{
    SkinnedOutput Out = (SkinnedOutput) 0;

    Out.Position = mul(_Input.Position, WorldMatrix);
    Out.Position = mul(Out.Position, ViewMatrix);
    Out.Position = mul(Out.Position, ProjectionMatrix);

    Out.Tex = _Input.Tex;

    Out.Normal = normalize(mul(float4(_Input.Normal, 0.f), WorldMatrix));

    
    return Out;

}
```

when i debug hlsl, there is no data in weights and boneindices like this

[image]

Anyone know about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have problem in input element for shader](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197102/i-have-problem-in-input-element-for-shader)

Comment: This appears to be quite similar to [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/197102/39518). Are you still struggling with the same issue? If so, please edit your existing question, and do not post multiple questions about solving the same issue.